# Magento admin routing isn't working

Tags: php, magento

I'm working on a module for the admin area of Magento.  I'm trying to follow Alan Storm's tutorial on [Magento admin controllers](http://alanstorm.com/magento_admin_controllers) but can't seem to get my controller to do anything.  I think it may have something to do with routing, but I'm not sure.  It shows me the frontend template with a 404 error.

(Note: *I have included all relevant code here.  The actual question is at the very bottom.*)

The module is called Mynamespace_Donor and lives in app/code/local/Mynamespace/Donor/.

My etc/config.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mynamespace_Donor>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Mynamespace_Donor>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <donor>
                <class>Mynamespace_Donor_Helper</class>
            </donor>
        </helpers>
        <resources>
            <donor_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Mynamespace_Donor</module>
                </setup>
            </donor_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>

    <admin>
        <routers>
            <donor>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Mynamespace_Donor</module>
                    <frontname>donor</frontname>
                </args>
            </donor>
        </routers>
    </admin>

    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <donor translate="title" module="donor">
                <title>Donor</title>
                <sort_order>42</sort_order>
                <children>
                    <manage_donors module="donor">
                        <title>Manage Donors</title>
                        <action>donor/index/index</action>
                    </manage_donors>
                </children>
            </donor>
        </menu>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

And my controllers/IndexController.php looks like this:

```
<?php
class Mynamespace_Donor_IndexController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();

        //create a text block with the name of "example-block"
        $block = $this->getLayout()
        ->createBlock('core/text', 'example-block')
        ->setText('<h1>This is a text block</h1>');

        $this->_addContent($block);

        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

The menu item points me to `/index.php/donor/index/index/key/e98a...` which shows a 404 page.  When I try to go directly to `/donor`, `/index.php/donor`, `/index.php/donor/index`, etc I still get 404 errors.

If I remove the `<helpers>` from the config, Magento complains that it can't find it.  If I remove the `<adminhtml>` section, it stops complaining, even though I still have my `<admin><routers>` section in there (don't know if the routing stuff needs a helper or if this is even relevant).

I've also tried adding this block under `<adminhtml>`, but it when I try editing role permissions I get a white page with this error: `Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Mynamespace_Donor_Helper_Data' not found in /home/mysite/public_html/magento_dev_1_10/app/Mage.php on line 520`

```
<acl>
    <resources>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <donor translate="title" module="Mynamespace_Donor">
                    <title>Donors</title>
                    <sort_order>60</sort_order>
                    <children>
                        <manage_donors>
                            <title>Manage Donors</title>
                        </manage_donors>
                    </children>
                </donor>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
```

**Question:** What am I doing wrong here?  Why can I not access this controller?

And lastly, in Alan's sample code, the URL began with the module name, but I would like mine to start with `/admin/donor` instead of `/donor`. What changes do I need to make for this?

---

**Edit 1**
The ultimate goal is to have a new tab in the admin area for managing Donors and related data in the system.  When you click on some menu item, I'd like to show a grid and have sub-tabs and stuff like that.  I'm *not* looking to override the adminhtml controller - although I am extending it per [Alan's suggestion](http://alanstorm.com/magento_admin_controllers):

> The only difference from a standard
>   controller here is that we’re
>   extending
>   Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
>   instead of
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action.
>   Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
>   contains important code for validating
>   the admin session, as well as several
>   methods that are useful in an Admin
>   Console context.

So in this picture, clicking that first sub-menu item should call the Index action of my controller and show a grid or something to manage the Donors.

[image: The menu]

Comment: Please consider using [the module creator](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/danieln/extension/1108/modulecreator) to build all this config stuff for you. It saves you from masses of boilerplater and (from memory) even has a template for an admin page with a grid.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll certainly start with that next time :) Or maybe if I get stuck on something else..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to replace :

```
<frontname>donor</frontname>
```

with :

```
<frontName>donor</frontName>
```

That will fix your 404 error.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks!  Why do the biggest problems always come down to a single character? :P  Any idea how I can make the URL start with "/admin/donor" instead of just "/donor"?

Comment: This answer is correct but redundant if using B00MER's answer.

Comment: @clockworkgeek - are you saying I need to use B00MER's solution to get the URL to start with '/admin'?

Comment: I tried setting `<frontName>` to `admin/donor` - that made the menu URL point to what I'd like (`/admin/donor/index/index`), but the 404 issue came back :-/

Comment: I've decided that the 'admin' prefix isn't worth the hassle at this point.  This got it working with it, so I'll accept this.  Thanks again to @clockworkgeek and @B00MER for the help! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 5):

```
<config>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <mynamespace_donor before="Mage_Adminhtml">Mynamespace_Donor</mynamespace_donor>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

Try the above in your config.xml

More details:

http://prattski.com/2010/06/24/magento-overriding-core-files-blocks-models-resources-controllers/

Comment: I think this overrides the adminhtml controller.  Is that really what I want to do?  I think I just want to extend it, to get some of the built-in functionality, but not interfere with anything else.

Comment: @Colin - This isn't exactly overriding adminhtml, just making sure that your controller is tried before any other, if the URL doesn't match your controller's actions then adminhtml is processed as normal. You could use this to override an existing action if you wanted, but that's a later lesson...

Comment: @clockworkgeek/B00MER - Gotcha, that makes sense.  I was able to get the desired URL to work via B00MER's answer, but every other tab in the admin area ends up 404ing.  My controller is named IndexController and my action is named indexAction.  Do I need to change the names of either one to prevent it from overriding these? If so, what should I name them and do I need to move any files around?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the fatal error; You have `module="Mynamespace_Donor"` in the permissions. If you look at Alan's tutorial he has:

```
<tutorial_menu translate="title" module="adminhelloworld">
```

He uses the *module alias* instead of the module name - `adminhelloworld` instead of `Alanstormdotcom_Adminhelloworld`. Magento is trying to find the helper relevant for translating the title. In your case you need:

```
<donor translate="title" module="donor">
```

The `donor` comes from your own config file:

```
<helpers>
    <donor> <!-- <<< This is the alias "donor" -->
        <class>Mynamespace_Donor_Helper</class>
    </donor>
</helpers>
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the permissions issue for me :)