# Unable to call magento admin controller

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, magento-1.9

I have created a **custom module** that **adds two menus** in **catalog**. I have also created a **controller** for one of the **menu** , but the controller never gets called but instead is redirected to the admin dashboard page.

My question is some what related to  this question [Magento admin routing isn't working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389081/magento-admin-routing-isnt-working?rq=1)

I have tried the suggestions mentioned in the answers but none of them worked for me.

When ever I call the url http://localhost/compare/index.php/ecomm/index/key/bb9f436ee373421b170aa862a1cbb305/

I get redirected to http://localhost/compare/index.php/admin/dashboard/index/key/bb9f436ee373421b170aa862a1cbb305/ and hello world never gets printed.

I'm using **magento 1.9** and have disabled all the caches.

My module name is **Super_Awesome** and below is the directory structure

```
Super
|
|-Awesome
  |-etc          (adminhtml.xml, config.xml)
  |-controllers  (ManageEcomm.php)
  |-Helper       (Data.php)
```

The config file in app/etc/modules/Super_Awesome.xml is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Super_Awesome>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Super_Awesome>
    </modules>
</config>
```

The config file in app/code/local/Super/Awesome/etc/config.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Super_Awesome>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Super_Awesome>
    </modules> 

    <admin>
        <routers>
            <ecomm>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Super_Awesome</module>
                    <frontName>ecomm</frontName>
                </args>
            </ecomm>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <!-- The <acl> section is for access control. Here we define the pieces where access can be controlled within a role. -->
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <catalog>
                            <!--<title>Awesome Menu Item</title>-->
                            <children>
                                <example translate="title" module="awesome">
                                    <title>Manage Ecommerce</title>
                                </example>
                                <example1 translate="title" module="awesome">
                                    <title>Manage Ecommerce Pages</title>
                                </example1>
                            </children>
                        </catalog>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>

    </adminhtml>

    <global>
        <helpers>
            <awesome>
                <class>Super_Awesome_Helper</class>
            </awesome>
        </helpers>
    </global>

</config>
```

Controller app/code/local/Super/Awesome/controllers/IndexController.php

```
<?php
class Super_Awesome_IndexController extends Mage_adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    { 
        echo "hello world";
        exit();
    }
}
```

Finally the adminhtml.xml file in app/code/local/Super/Awesome/etc/

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <catalog translate="title" module="awesome">
            <!--<title>Awesome</title>
            <sort_order>15</sort_order>-->
            <children>
                <example translate="title" module="awesome">
                    <title>Manage Ecommerce</title>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/ecomm</action>
                </example>
                <example1 translate="title" module="awesome">
                    <title>Manage Ecommerce Pages</title>
                    <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/example/index</action>
                </example1>
            </children>
        </catalog>
    </menu>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it the hard way that it's not good to create a module by yourself. If you make a mistake you could end up your precious time finding where things went wrong.

Its best to install a module creator extension from [Ultimate Module Creator](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ultimate-module-creator.html) or use a online tool provided by [Silk](http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/)

Comment: Yes, there are many details that have to be right so it can be error prone to create extensions for Magento. Glad you found a tool that helped you solve your problem. You should expand your answer to explain what went wrong and then accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have missed the part where you [add your new module as a router for `adminhtml`](http://alanstorm.com/magento_admin_hello_world_revisited) in `etc/config.xml`. It should be something like this:

> When Magento tries to find a controller file for an admin URL, it will also check for any module configured inside this `<modules/>` tag.

```
<config>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Super_Awesome after="Mage_Adminhtml">Super_Awesome</Super_Awesome>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

Comment: Thanks, for your quick reply. If I add this block of xml, what would be my corresponding url? I have both the xmls. http://localhost/compare/index.php/admin/super/awesome/index/key/e0503149a3834de0cdad2c42eb055775/ shows 404, while the previous url redirects me to the dashboard page.

Comment: @Searock - You may need to log out of admin and log back in before the new route starts working. That’s usually what 404 displayed inside the admin template means.

Comment: Its not working, I have added the block which you have said plus    `<admin>
        <routers>
            <ecomm>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Super_Awesome</module>
                    <frontName>ecomm</frontName>
                </args>
            </ecomm>
        </routers>
    </admin>`

Comment: I referred to Alan Storm's tutorial and his code worked. Still not sure what is wrong with my code. By the way you both belong to the same country, by any chance are you Alan?

Comment: @Searock - Hah, no I am not [Alan Storm](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4668/alan-storm). Which part is not working and what is happening now?

Comment: The url does not work, if i use http://localhost/compare/index.php/ecomm/index/key/bb9f436ee373421b170aa862a1cbb305/ I get redirected to the dashboard and if I use http://localhost/compare/index.php/admin/dashboard/index/key/bb9f436ee373421b170aa862a1cbb305/ I get 404.

Comment: @Searock - I’m not sure if this matters, but typically `adminhtml` controllers go into the subdirectory `controllers/Adminhtml/` so in your case it would be `Super/Awesome/controllers/Adminhtml/IndexController.php` and the class name would be `Super_Awesome_Adminhtml_IndexController` corresponding to URL `/admin/ecomm/index/index/`.